# Bootstrap to wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, http-headers, wp-nav-walker

I have been converting a bootstrap theme into a wordpress theme, discovered that the nav did not work, included the nav walker class file and everything worked OK for a while.

Now how ever when I log in to instant wordpress and try to launch the site I get this

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\Users\William Banks\Desktop\InstantWP_4.5\iwpserver\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\ST-bootstrap\functions.php:122) in C:\Users\William Banks\Desktop\InstantWP_4.5\iwpserver\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\pluggable.php on line 1174

and I can't for the life of me figure it out.

Comment: What text editor do you use?

Comment: @whizzer: can you share the code which you have written in `htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\ST-bootstrap\functions.php:122`.

Comment: Yes do you have a email i can send to. Thanks William

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-sdPfX6_PdjSXRRakpNZkZrNU0 you can view my code here thanks whizzer

Comment: I use Brackets for all coding at the moment - Makshh

Comment: Check if your file (functions.php) has UTF-8 encoding (without BOM) and remove all unncessary white spaces and line breaks at the end of your file (after `?>`)

Comment: How do i check if my functions.php has UTF-8 (without BOM) ? Please.

Comment: It;s only when i include the walker class i get an issue?

Comment: It looks like it was white space after reading about the subject, Thanks Makshh you were very helpful. Cheers dude.

Comment: If somebody else is reading this, I also had small problem with my header.php, this problem is now solved. Have a look into the meta data and make sure you have the char set info the way wordpress likes it.